# How to save a viewer specific option

Tags: globals, cookies

A minimal example of my problem would be

- default background colour is white
- a custom sidebar widget offers to switch background colour to green
- when switched to green, background shall stay green while exploring the blog

Is there a standard interface in Wordpress for saving a global PHP variable $bgcolor to the viewer and read it from him anytime he browses to another blog page.

(I'd like to avoid setting a cookie "by hand")

Comment: Why do you like to avoid setting a cookie? Saving data for the user's session is made for a `$_SESSION` cookie.

Comment: @MikeMadern Seems solid. I was so stubbornly looking for a WordPress way I ignored PHP standards ...

Comment: And here is a [HowTo](http://devondev.com/2012/02/03/using-the-php-session-in-wordpress/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a standard interface in Wordpress for saving a global PHP
>   variable $bgcolor to the user and read it from him anytime he browses
>   to another blog page.

There is nothing that will automagically do it for you but it sounds like you just need to [save a little bit of user meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta), and of course [retrieve it](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta).

Since you asked about saving the variable, I am going to assume that the custom sidebar widget that switches the background color already works. Just add code, based on the two Codex entries above, that checks the user meta and saves changes.

If you post your code, I may be able to give a more elaborate answer.

If you are talking about generic visitors, and not WordPress users, setting a cookie is your best choice. There are no built in generic "cookie setter" functions that I am aware of. WordPress itself uses PHP's [`setcookie`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) in a fair few places, for example in [`wp_set_auth_cookie`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L680), and I don't know why that function would need a "helper". It is fairly straighforward.